# SQL Server 2012 Group only by one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to group only by one column

SQL Server 2012 query:

```
SELECT OrderID,Status,DateEdited 
FROM orders 
WHERE Status='Pending' 
GROUP BY OrderID,Status,DateEdited
```

and the result is:

[image]

As you can see there are duplicate `OrderId` column values.

Works but it groups by `OrderId,Status,DateEdit` but what I need is that the `OrderId` would be unique in the results can I have something like:

```
SELECT OrderID,Status,DateEdited 
FROM orders 
WHERE Status='Pending' 
GROUP BY OrderID
```

Comment: What value for the other two fields should be picked?

Comment: The rows are not **duplicate** - they differ in their values ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use an aggregate function for `status` and `DateEdited`, to get distinct valeus for each grouped `ORDERID`. You can also use the ranking functions to do so like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT 
     OrderID,
     Status,
     DateEdited,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY DateEdited DESC) rownum
   FROM orders 
   WHERE Status='Pending'
)
SELECT 
  OrderID,
  Status,
  DateEdited
FROM CTE
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

This will give you distinct `ORDERID`s. But which status and `DateEdited` to return for each grouped `ORDERID`?

Comment: The more reasonable assumption is to take the most recent edited value, not the oldest edited value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Sorry, fixed now Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Then you can do like this,

```
SELECT OrderID,'Pending' as Status,max(DateEdited) 
FROM orders 
WHERE Status='Pending' 
GROUP BY OrderID
```

If you dont want to loose any record then you can go for 
GROUP_CONCAT()

```
SELECT OrderID,'Pending' as Status,GROUP_CONCAT(DateEdited) 
FROM orders 
WHERE Status='Pending' 
GROUP BY OrderID
```

**Note: Am not sure whether you GROUP_CONCAT in sqlserver** Incase it's not there
go for a function like that. :)